# Iterating for a specific array element in Python

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I'm using in my Python something like this:

```
for i in range(333333):
    array1[i,1]=numpy.where(array1[i,1]!=-1,array[i,1],function(array1[i,0],array1,array2))
```

Obviously, this is not really computationally feasible because of the size of the arrays, so I would like to modify this in a way that the loop can be removed. I initially tried:

```
array1[:,1]=numpy.where(array1[:,1]!=-1,array1[:,1],function(array1[:,0],array1,array2))
```

However, this is not working as expected, because the first argument that the function is picking is the whole column of array1, and not just an element like in the code above. Is there any other way to make this work as with the loop? Any suggestions are of great help.

Edit: To make more clear what I'm looking for, I'll include what could be the input with just 3 iterations on the loop:

```
import numpy as np

def function(parameter:float,sample1:np.ndarray,sample2:np.ndarray) -> float:

    value=sample2[np.where(sample2[:,0]==parameter),1]
    
    return value[0,0]

array1=np.zeros((3,2))
array2=np.zeros((3,2))

array1=np.array([[1.,-1.],[2.,2.75],[3.,-1.]])
array2=np.array([[1.,0.75],[2.,-1.],[3.,4.56]])

for i in range(3):
    array1[i,1]=np.where(array1[i,1]!=-1,array1[i,1],function(array1[i,0],array1,array2))
    i+=1
```

In this case, the variable "parameter" is going through the function component by component, so printing array1 at the end gives:

```
[[1.   0.75]
 [2.   2.75]
 [3.   4.56]]
```

However, if I change the loop and I use:

```
array1[:,1]=np.where(array1[:,1]!=-1,array1[:,1],function(array1[:,0],array1,array2))
```

Then the function uses the whole column of array1 as the argument instead of just a value, resulting in an unexpected modification of array1:

```
[[1.   0.75]
 [2.   2.75]
 [3.   0.75]]
```

Comment: Please provide some example code and a sample input with expected output.